# jQueryMobile pageInit, "Can't find variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I followed the introduction of the official jQuery Mobile docs:

> Important: Use pageInit(), not $(document).ready()

but, when I write:

```
pageInit(function()
    alert('ahhh');
});
```

my Safari Console tells me: `Cant find variable "pageInit"`

Why is this? How can I use the function `pageInit()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$( '#aboutPage' ).live( 'pageinit',function(event){
  alert( 'haa!' );
});
```

or with JQuery 1.7

```
$("#myPage").on('pageinit', function(event){
    alert('haa');
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/on/

http://api.jquery.com/live/

btw in JQMobile its recommended to use Jquery 1.6.4, thus, first example is the right one.

zY

Comment: FYI jQuery 1.7 is not yet supported by jQueryMobile 1.0

Comment: FYI it works anyway. And is much faster in some on()-nested methods. But thats my subjective opinion. BTW I edited it after writing the comment "btw in JQMobile its recommended to use Jquery 1.6.4, thus, first example is the right one."